# Scale-free network or not?

Tags: r, distributions, social-network, scale-invariance

I am working on a directed graph, where in and out degree distributions are extrimely different: while the in-degree is for sure following a power-law, the out degree is not. Also, the in degree is a huge portion of the total one. I have checked the power-law hypothesis as suggested [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/b_powerlaw_examples.pdf), and got a *p-value* of 0.88 which should mean the whole degree distribution is following nicely a power-law. I also extimated the gamma parameter, and got that it should be around 2.6, suggesting that the regime my network is following is an ultra-small world. Only after doing this and viewing a significant difference between the theorical and actual average distance (2.5 vs 8), I thought that it could be wrong defining the network as scale free since the out-degree is not following a power-law distribution at all. Here you can see the distributions of in, out and total degree:
[image: In-degree distribution] [image: Out-degree distribution] [image: Degree distribution]

Basically, I think the whole analysis I have done on this network, calling it scale free and supposing it to be like that, is garbage because of this.
I would be extremely interested in reading others opionions and am hoping for someone to write me that I am wrong and that this is in fact a scale free network.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your first plot is identical to the plot in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531494/what-distribution-is-this).

Comment: Great, I suppose he is working on the same data. This question asks something totally different though.